# under what circumstances CURRENT file will be missing under rocksdb database directory

Tags: rocksdb

At times, our application fails to start with error "CURRENT : does not exist ( create_if_missing is false )". I am sure, it has some thing to do with our app shutdown. we are doing a delete db. what can go wrong ??

Answer (score 1):

It should always be present as long as the DB is not corrupted.

> we are doing a delete db.

If you are doing deletion to the db, make sure DeleteDBFile is not deleting the current file or you are not deleting the whole db folder which contains the CURRENT file. Please check the db folder by ls (or equivelant) to see if the CURRENT file presents upon your shutdown that is not supposed to delete CURRENT file if that isn't your intention.